# Issue with printing a pointer of array in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I'm facing this issue right now and I hope to find clarification and a solution.
Actually, my code is running without any problems, it's just when I wish to print the
pointer to a char array, it is not printing in the desired way.
Should I use a multidimensional array? I'm confused.

I'm new to c language so my code might be a little bit messy:>

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main() {
        int no_of_customers;
        char customer_name[SIZE];
        char* customer_namePtr[SIZE];
    
        printf("enter number of customers you wish to add ");
    
        scanf_s("%d", &no_of_customers);
    
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < no_of_customers; ++i, ++j) {
            printf("Enter %d customer's name ", j + 1);
            scanf_s("%9s", &customer_name[i], 10);
            customer_namePtr[i] = &customer_name[i];
        }
        puts("");
    
        printf("customer name's are:\n");
    
        for (size_t i = 0; i < no_of_customers; ++i) {
            printf("%9s", customer_namePtr[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: “it is not printing in the desired way” is not an adequate problem description. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including sample input that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the desired output. Identify which particular `printf` is not working as you would like.

Comment: i have edited and made the code as clear as possible!

Comment: i meant the last printf when i needed to print the name of customer's

Comment: for example, if I wanted to print the name's Ali and Zayn. it prints the first iteration as AZayn and the second as Zayn. @EricPostpischil

Comment: Your code has only one array of `char` for the customer name, the one defined with `char customer_name[SIZE];`. So it can remember only one name. In `scanf("%9s", &customer_name[i]);`, you tell `scanf` to read input into the array starting at position `i`. That is why `Zayn` is put into the array starting at position 1, overwriting most of the `Ali` that starts at position 0. What has your class learned recently? Pointers? `malloc`? Two-dimensional arrays? Use the concepts that were taught recently to remember more than one name.

Comment: yes, I understood the logic of how the execution occurred. so far we learned about pointers and multi-dimensional arrays. can I use multi-dimensional arrays in this case?. in addition, I have used a pointer to print the names. also, I am required not to only print 2 names, it depends on how many customers I wish to add.

Comment: "can I use multi-dimensional arrays in this case?" -- yes, you must (in this case). P.S. your `customer_namePtr` array is useless; get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char customer_name[10];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < no_of_customers; ++i, ++j)
{
    scanf_s("%9s", &customer_name[i], 10);
    ...
}
```

Your existing code has potential buffer overrun. Note that `customer_name` is just a 1-D character array. In the first iteration, it writes to zero index, which is fine. But in the 10th iteration, it writes to `customer_name[9]` and adds up to 10 more characters after that. This is writing to some random memory address outside of `customer_name`. Also the debugger should complain because `scanf_s` is being used, it should detect memory corruption in the second iteration.

The correct usage of `scanf_s` can be simply written as

```
scanf_s("%9s", customer_name, 10);
```

If you are going to assign a "string" to "array of strings", then it should be

```
customer_namePtr[i] = customer_name;
```

But this will not give the desired behavior, because all array elements point to the same buffer.

Instead you can declare a 2-D array, that is array of strings, as shown in the  example.

Ideally you should declare `char** customer_name = NULL;` and allocate using `malloc`, and allocate using `malloc` again for each element in `customer_name`

```
#define MAX_NAMESIZE 10
#define MAX_CUSTOMERS 10

int main()
{
    char buffer[MAX_NAMESIZE];
    char customer_name[MAX_CUSTOMERS][MAX_NAMESIZE];

    printf("enter number of customers you wish to add\n");
    int no_of_customers = 2;
    if (scanf_s("%d", &no_of_customers) != 1)
        return 0; //print input error
    if (no_of_customers < 0 || no_of_customers >= MAX_CUSTOMERS)
        return 0; //print input error

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_customers; i++) 
    {
        printf("Enter %d customer's name ", i + 1);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0; //remove the trailing '\n'
        strcpy(customer_name[i], buffer);
    }

    printf("customer name's are:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_customers; ++i) 
        printf("%9s\n", customer_name[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```